# Is using Zend Framework a good idea to create a Social Networking website?

Tags: php, zend-framework, cakephp, codeigniter, social-networking

I'm asking because some people say that Zend Framework is not very effective when it comes to speed. Today I know the following frameworks: SpaghettiFramework, CodeIgniter, CakePHP and Zend, What is the best choice for creating a social network? Thanks.

Comment: If you are wondering. Your question was closed because mentioning frameworks often just leads to boring popularity contests. And the choice has little influence over what type of applications you can build with it. (And you didn't even ask if any of those frameworks supports any exchange protocols like XMPP, FOAF, OpenID, etc. which would make sense for "social networks".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much a matter of opinion, but my vote goes to CodeIgniter.  Very lightweight, very elegant, very fast.

Many of these 'frameworks' are heavy and bloated, and not really appropriate for high-performance situations.  Some people like the 'swiss army knife' one-size-fits-all framework based approach, but this rarely results in the creation of an elegant and equally successful product.

Comment: and while we are at the things CI is "very" at, how about adding very crappy codebase (!= elegant) and very wrong understanding of design patterns (AR, MVC) - but yeah, you can be productive with it.

Comment: Like I said, a matter of opinion.  CI doesn't force users into strict MVC methodology, but it allows for users who know what they are doing to implement the pattern.  I don't think it is fair to call that a flaw in the framework.

Comment: it's not a matter of opinion. It's a fact. CI's AR is not an AR and their suggested M equals DB. Both is wrong. And I've never seen a CI user who actually knew what he was doing (but that just as an opinionated sidenote)

Comment: Not true - CI permits creation and utilization of models.  Your 'opinionated sidenote' is nothing more than an insult, sir.

Comment: Might be that it allows for that, but they dont suggest to do that. [From CI Docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html): "The Model represents your data structures. Typically your model classes will contain functions that help you retrieve, insert, and update information in your database." and that's just wrong. Persistence is just one layer among many in the Model.

Comment: I agree that the docs display a poor formal description of what a model should be.  With that said, the CI documentation exists to document the framework, _not_ to teach people how to program.